# What is the ideal Run Zone

Tags: running-training-plan

About me:

I'm 40y old. I'm training in martial arts for more than 20y. Nowadays I'm not competing in Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu, but the main set is still there (training and fight as hard as possible) anymore but I'm training as much as I can. It means in a good week I'm doing 2 runs of 5km, 2 WOD and 3 sessions of Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu.

During the lockdown in Australia, I increased my Running session to 4x week (3x 5km and 1x 7km) and my WOD.

Looking at my Garmin watch it said I'm not improving, after investigation it was because my run was too hard. I started to start slow and after a while increase the speed.

I'm researching what could be a good zone of training.

This was my typical training with a competitor mentality. I was trying to run as fast as possible.
[image]

After some research I read the recommendation is to slow down to get better and improve. Then I started to archive this:[image]

I know every case is different, but I'm trying to understand is if I should focus on stay longer on zone 3 and 4, or because I'm ok with my conditioning (maybe is better to say I can) I can continue to run on must of the time on Zone 5.

I want to improve my cardio for an under 30min exercice.

Comment: Are you doing any speed work?

Comment: Only my WOD. It's called Murphy (1.5km rum + 10x 10pull-ups, 20push-ups, 30squats + 1.5km) with a vest of 6kg

Comment: In general (IMO anyway) most running should max out at threshold, but try throwing in a single speed day/week, like 200m repeats. Searching around will find a lot of speed day options. Murph runs aren’t speed days ;)

Comment: "I want to improve my cardio for an under 30min exercice." - Most of the time, specific beats general. What are you planning on doing for that 30 min exercise? For running, most people spend their time running way too hard.